# Database Design: Include Question Answer and Comment tables into Post table

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database. This system has question, answer and comment.

- *Question* has some type of questions. In each type, there some differences so they're have some difference fields.
- *Answer* and comment have some slight differences too.

But both those three tables have some same things: *UserID, content, DateCreated, VoteUp, VoteDown, Share* ...

- With those similar, should I combine *question*, *answer* and *comment* into one table name Post?
- Has an additional field to tell which kind of this post?
- Which advantages and disadvantages for this way?

Comment: Take a look at open source "clones" of StackExchange [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37953)

Comment: Well it all depends on the expected data volume and query patterns, can you give more information about these ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost Query Pattern. Can you tell me more about this, please. In fact, I see that divide into two tables can make everything looks clearer and gain a little performance. thanks :)

Comment: But if I divide into two tables, I will meet some problems with ORM framework. The generating model doesn't know how reference key is from question or answer (because it needs a mark variable)